# Facebook submit iOS App for Review while working on Android App

Tags: android, ios, facebook

We currently developing an app for two platforms, iOS and Android. The development state of the iOs app is more advanced than the state of the Android app. We need facebook for authentication and we also want the “publish_actions” permission to post open graph actions on the users wall.

For our iOs app we reached a level were we want to submit for review. Unfortunately this is not true for the android app. 
As far as we know we have to remove the android platform from the Settings (https://developers.facebook.com/apps//settings/) if don’t want that facebook review it. But if we do this our android developers are not able to use the facebook authentication and therefore they can not work on the app in a proper way.

Our question: is there a way to submit for review for iOs only without losing the possibility to develop the android app? Or should we send our "not ready" android app to facebook review?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, we found a working answer by ourselves. 
On the facebook developers website we added a new app. There you can choose if this app should be a test version of an existing app. If you say yes, you get a ready test version of your existing app. 
After that you have to direct you “development versions” of your app to the new app id etc and do not forget to test it. For example in ios you have to set FacebookAppID and the URL Schemes to the new AppId and AppName.
If it works you can remove your “not ready for submission” platforms from the settings of your normal app (not the test version) and submit for login review.